# How to add a corner badge to a WordPress site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, genesis

I need to add a corner badge for our 10th anniversary. The problem is that we're using WordPress with genesis and epik theme.
I can't add a div to the header.php on the epik (child) theme because there's not a file. The header.php is on genesis.

Does anybody knows what's the correct way to do that?

[image]

Comment: you can put a div represent the badge on the footer or even on the index and make position fixed or absolute

Answer (score 0):

Add below code into your **current theme's functions.php** file.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'addbadge' );
function addbadge(){
 ?><style type="text/css">
   .badge{
     position: fixed;
     display: block;
     top: 28 px;
     left: -68px;
     width: 257px;
     z-index: 99999;
     background: #990a0a ;
     padding: 8px;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #d2d200 ;
     border-top: 2px solid #d2d200 ;
     transform: rotate(-39deg);
     text-align: center;
   }
   .badge a {
     color: #fff;
     font-weight: 900;
     text-decoration: none;
   }
 </style>
 <div class="badge">
   <a href="url">Fork Me On GitHub</a>
 </div><?php
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Thanks!

Comment: it doesn't works... just added it but nothing appears. contidosdixitais.com